# Python - How to make a class method that receives any number of args and returns a list of all args?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I created a Class called Manager as a sub-class of Employee and am trying to create a regular method for addind employees to the manager's supervision. However I want this method to receive any number of arguments (number of employees) so I added the * when defining the method:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    # Returns employees fullname
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)


class Manager(Employee):

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, employees=None):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        if employees is None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees

    def add_emp(self, *emp):           # Accept any no. of args
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(emp)

    def print_emps(self):              # Prints all employees' names
        for emp in self.employees:
            print('-->', emp.fullname())
```

When I run the code addind emps like (emp_1, emp_2, emp_3) they're added, but when it comes to print their name an error occurs:

```
emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000)
emp_2 = Employee('Test', 'User', 60000)
mng_1 = Manager('Roger', 'Smith', 100000)

mng_1.add_emp(emp_1, emp_2)
mng_1.print_emps()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fullname'
```

How could input as many args as I want as a list so the attributes and methods of the class remain working for each item?

Comment: In the Employee class, it seems that the values being returned are a tuple.  There seems to be a method that is returning multiple objects, which are treated as tuples in python.  And tuple objects won't have Employee attributes.

Comment: You need to post the code where you test this function.

Comment: @Sid If I get rid of the * and add the employees one by one as:
    manager.add_emp(emp_1)
    manager.add_emp(emp_2)

They're added in a List and then I can use the Employee attributes and methods. But if I leave the * it automatically adds them to a Tuple

Comment: The problem is that `*emp` is a tuple (similar to a list) of employees, but the code in `add_emp` is treating `emp` as a single record. You should use `*emps`, then `for emp in emps:`, then within that, your existing code. Not putting this as an answer because this is a simple logic error.

Comment: @JimStewart But why not having the for loop adds the args to a tuple and not a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your add_emp method like this:

```
def add_emp(self, *emps):           # Accept any no. of args
    for emp in emps:
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(emp)
```

Comment: Kkkkkkkk why does it work?
It's like the for loop makes the * add the args to a list

Comment: emps is a tuple (like a list) of the arguments. If you want to do something with each of them, you iterate over the tuple with "for emp in emps"